# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS missing index that is shown with SHOW INDEX in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

The NodeJS ORM [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) uses `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` [to show constraints](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/73f1b5d1d3cd010286e4db5fdb7e1baee22cd1f6/lib/dialects/mysql/query-generator.js#L317) and I am running into an issue where a constraint is not showing up in that query but it does exist and therefore I cannot alter the constraint in a sequelize migration.

I am not sure if this is a sequelize problem or if this is a MySQL problem but the raw SQL that has me scratching my head is:

```
mysql> use rypedb; SHOW INDEX FROM teacher_information;
Database changed
+---------------------+------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+--------
| Table               | Non_unique | Key_name                          | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment
+---------------------+------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+--------
| teacher_information |          0 | PRIMARY                           |            1 | id          | A         |         143 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |
| teacher_information |          1 | teacher_information_teacher_id_fk |            1 | account_id  | A         |         143 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |
+---------------------+------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+--------
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'teacher_information_teacher_id_fk' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'rypedb';
Empty set, 2 warnings (0.01 sec)
```

Is it expected that the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` should not have the index that is shown in the `SHOW INDEX` query? It does show other constraints and this is the first time I have seen this issue.

This is the output of my create table statement:

```
| teacher_information | CREATE TABLE `teacher_information` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_url` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bio_link` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `teacher_information_teacher_id_fk` (`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=144 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: The name of a constraint is not always the same as the name of the key. Try `WHERE table_name = 'teacher_information'`

Comment: @Barmar still no index shown

Comment: Can you show the output of `show create table teacher_information`?

Comment: This looks like what you would see if you had a foreign key constraint, but removed it. The FK creates a non-unique index and a foreign key constraint, removing the FK removes the constraint but leaves the index.

Comment: Hmm @Barmar maybe somehow I did get into a bad state. Create table statement is above

Comment: I concur with Barmar. What's wrong here seems to be the expectation that the  name of a foreign key *constraint* will match the name of an *index* (key), or that a foreign key constraint exists for a given index. It's also possible for two (or more) FK constraints to use the same index. There's no bad state shown, unless the intent is that there should be a foreign key constraint e.g. `CONSTRAINT teacher_information_teacher_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES foo (bar) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT`. i.e. it's valid to have an index without having a foreign key constraint).

Comment: Yep, this looks like you removed the FK constraint on `account_id`, but didn't remove the index.

Comment: I think it should because I did this through the sequelize ORM but I also think @Barmar is right in that somehow this got into a bad state.

Comment: Add the FK back and you should get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constraint is not the same thing as an index.

Here's an example of a table with a PRIMARY KEY, a secondary UNIQUE KEY, a FOREIGN KEY, a CHECK constraint, and another index that is not a constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`bar` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foo_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `unique_int` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nonunique_int` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_int` (`unique_int`),
  KEY `my_fk` (`foo_id`),
  KEY `nonunique_int` (`nonunique_int`),
  CONSTRAINT `bar_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`) REFERENCES `foo` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `my_chk` CHECK ((`nonunique_int` in (1,2,3)))
)
```

Here's what is in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS:

```
select * from table_constraints where table_schema='test' and table_name='bar';
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+----------+
| CONSTRAINT_CATALOG | CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | CONSTRAINT_NAME | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | CONSTRAINT_TYPE | ENFORCED |
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+----------+
| def                | test              | PRIMARY         | test         | bar        | PRIMARY KEY     | YES      |
| def                | test              | unique_int      | test         | bar        | UNIQUE          | YES      |
| def                | test              | bar_ibfk_1      | test         | bar        | FOREIGN KEY     | YES      |
| def                | test              | my_chk          | test         | bar        | CHECK           | YES      |
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+----------+
```

Here's what's in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS table for the same table:

```
select * from statistics where table_schema='test' and table_name='bar';
+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+----------+------------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+
| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | NON_UNIQUE | INDEX_SCHEMA | INDEX_NAME    | SEQ_IN_INDEX | COLUMN_NAME   | COLLATION | CARDINALITY | SUB_PART | PACKED | NULLABLE | INDEX_TYPE | COMMENT | INDEX_COMMENT | IS_VISIBLE | EXPRESSION |
+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+----------+------------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+
| def           | test         | bar        |          1 | test         | my_fk         |            1 | foo_id        | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES      | BTREE      |         |               | YES        | NULL       |
| def           | test         | bar        |          1 | test         | nonunique_int |            1 | nonunique_int | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES      | BTREE      |         |               | YES        | NULL       |
| def           | test         | bar        |          0 | test         | PRIMARY       |            1 | id            | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |          | BTREE      |         |               | YES        | NULL       |
| def           | test         | bar        |          0 | test         | unique_int    |            1 | unique_int    | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES      | BTREE      |         |               | YES        | NULL       |
+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+----------+------------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+
```

This shows a PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE KEY and FOREIGN KEY do implicitly create indexes, but:

- CHECK does not create an index
- KEY does not create a constraint

Comment: In MySQL 8.0 `CHECK` should create a constraint.

Comment: +10 highlighting that CONSTRAINT is not the same thing as INDEX (KEY)

Comment: @Barmar, Yes, I tested on 8.0.16 and the CHECK constraint did create a row in the TABLE_CONSTRAINTS table. The constraint_name is `my_chk` and it is present.